# Extract the counts and the percentages of them in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | dog | NA |
| 2 | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | cat | dog | cat |
| 4 | NA | NA | NA |
| 5 | cat | dog | NA |
| 6 | NA | dog | dog |
| 7 | NA | dog | NA |
| 8 | NA | dog | NA |
| 9 | cat | cat | cat |
| 10 | dog | cat | dog |

I want to calculate how many counts of each variable cat and dog appear in each column and calculate their percentage BUT WITHOUT specifying to search the specific names.
Ideally I want the output to be 3 tables that must look like this:

|  | A | per |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | 3 | 3/4 |
| dog | 1 | 1/4 |

|  | B | per |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | 2 | 2/6 |
| dog | 4 | 4/6 |

|  | C | per |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | 2 | 2/4 |
| dog | 2 | 2/4 |

How I can do that using dplyr?

```
id = seq(1:10)
A = c("NA","NA","cat","NA","cat","NA","NA","NA","cat","dog")
B = c("dog","NA","dog","NA","cat","dog","dog","dog","cat","cat")
C = c("NA","NA","cat","NA","NA","dog","NA","NA","cat","dog")
frame = tibble(id,A,B,C);frame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

frame %>% pivot_longer(!id, names_to = "group", values_to = "animal") %>%
  mutate(animal = na_if(animal, "NA")) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(group, animal) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% mutate(per = n / sum(n))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'group'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   group animal     n   per
#>   <chr> <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1 A     cat        3 0.75 
#> 2 A     dog        1 0.25 
#> 3 B     cat        3 0.375
#> 4 B     dog        5 0.625
#> 5 C     cat        2 0.5  
#> 6 C     dog        2 0.5
```

or if you really want three separate tables, you can do

```r
frame %>% pivot_longer(!id, names_to = "group", values_to = "animal") %>%
  mutate(animal = na_if(animal, "NA")) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(group, animal) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% mutate(per = n / sum(n)) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  map(~ pivot_wider(.x, names_from = "group", values_from = "n") %>%
        relocate(per, .after = last_col()))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'group'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   animal     A   per
#>   <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1 cat        3  0.75
#> 2 dog        1  0.25
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   animal     B   per
#>   <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1 cat        3 0.375
#> 2 dog        5 0.625
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   animal     C   per
#>   <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1 cat        2   0.5
#> 2 dog        2   0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's bit messy

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

frame2 <- frame %>%
  reshape2::melt(id.vars = "id") %>%
  filter(value != "NA") # or na.omit()
frame2
res <- list()
l <- unique(frame2$variable)
for (i in 1:length(l)){
  dd <- frame2 %>%
    filter(variable == l[i]) %>%
    group_by(variable, value) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = value, values_from = c(n, freq), names_from = variable) %>%
    column_to_rownames(var = "value")
  colnames(dd) <- c(as.character(l[i]), "per")
  res[[i]] <- dd
}
res

[[1]]
    A  per
cat 3 0.75
dog 1 0.25

[[2]]
    B   per
cat 3 0.375
dog 5 0.625

[[3]]
    C per
cat 2 0.5
dog 2 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```r
sapply(colnames(frame)[-1], function(n) {
  tab <- table(frame[, n], exclude='NA')
  tab <- cbind(tab, tab / sum(tab))
  colnames(tab) <- c(n, 'per')
  tab
}, simplify=F)

# $A
#     A  per
# cat 3 0.75
# dog 1 0.25
# 
# $B
#     B   per
# cat 3 0.375
# dog 5 0.625
# 
# $C
#     C per
# cat 2 0.5
# dog 2 0.5
```

Or if you really wanted the x/y format for 'per' column:

```r
sapply(colnames(frame)[-1], function(n) {
  tab <- table(frame[, n], exclude='NA')
  tab <- data.frame(c(tab), paste0(tab, '/', sum(tab)))
  colnames(tab) <- c(n, 'per')
  tab
}, simplify=F)

# $A
#     A per
# cat 3 3/4
# dog 1 1/4
#
# $B
#     B per
# cat 3 3/8
# dog 5 5/8
#
# $C
#     C per
# cat 2 2/4
# dog 2 2/4
```